# Alertar quando o scroll chegar ao topo da página

Tags: jquery

No código abaixo, o alerta é acionado quando o scroll chega no final.

```
$('#messages').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height() == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
        alert('a rolagem chegou ao fim, fazer algo aqui.');
    }
});
```

Porém, no carregamento da página, o scroll é iniciado no bottom.

Como posso fazer ao inverso do código acima, e alertar quando o scroll chegar ao  topo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

É só colocar um `else if` verificando se a rolagem chegou a `0`:

> Coloquei um `Math.ceil()` no exemplo apenas para funcionar
>   corretamente no snippet.

```js
$('#messages').scroll(function() {
    if (Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) == $(this).get(0).scrollHeight) {
        console.log('a rolagem chegou ao fim, fazer algo aqui.');
    }else if($(this).scrollTop() == 0){
        console.log('a rolagem chegou ao início, fazer algo aqui.');
    }
});
```

```css
html, body{
   overflow: hidden;
   height: 100vh;
}

#messages{
   height: 50%;
   overflow: auto;
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages">
   mensagens início
   <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
   mensagens fim<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
$('#messages').scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() == 0) {
        alert('a rolagem chegou ao inicio, fazer algo aqui.');
    }
});
```